# Why doesn't std::basic_string::substr follow the [begin, end) convention?

Tags: c++, string, range, substr

The method [`std::basic_string::substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) has the arguments `pos, count`, specifying the logical range of elements in positions *[pos, pos + count + 1)*. Conversely, most of the standard library functions (for example, [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each)) have arguments, of some form similar to `begin, end`, specifying the range *[begin, end)*

This seems to be an exception, then, confusing to some (see the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726635/stdstring-substr-method-problems), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477850/c-string-substr-function-problem), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31465277/substr-method-in-c), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810024/why-is-substr-generating-different-results)). Why wasn't the usual range convention used here? Note also that [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), a method of another random-access container, *does* follow the usual convention.

Comment: You can get same behaviour by using contrustor. E.g. `std::string substring{text.begin(), text.end()}`. Do not know why `substr` does not have such overload.

Comment: @Zereges: Because it's redundant. If you have the two iterators denoting the substring, why pass them to a `std::string::substr()` overload if you can also pass them to `std::string::string()`.

Comment: @MSalters There are lot of redundant overloads or even functions in STL. STL is not designed to be minimalistic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Historical reasons. The Standard Library has multiple origins, one of which is the STL. It brought the `begin,end` convention. `std::string` predates the merger of the STL into the Standard Library, and there was plenty of existing code that used `.substr(pos,length)`.

Comment: ... and I think if we were designing the library now, `std::string` would look very different.

Answer (score 5):

A simple guess:

The different methods you cite have different behavior, which is probably why some use iterators and other don't.

`std::for_each` is generic - The easiest way to have a generic version of a method that works on any containers (and even on raw array) is to use iterators.

`std::vector::erase` is part of the [SequenceContainer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/SequenceContainer) concept, so it must have a "generic" form that can work on any kind of container (you could use `pos` and `count` for a `std::vector`, but what about an `std::list`? Or a `std::set`?). Having such concept is useful to create generic code:

```
template <typename C>
void real_remove(C &c, const typename C::value_type &value) {
     c.erase(std::remove(c.begin(), c.end(), value), c.end());
}
```

This only works because `std::...::erase` is well-defined for any SequenceContainer.

On the other hand, `std::basic_string::substr` is only part of `std::basic_string` (unlike `erase` which is part of `std::vector`, `std::list`, ...) and returns a `std::basic_string`<sup>1</sup> (not an iterator, what would you do with an iterator here?).

There are other "non-generic" (i.e. that are not mandatory by some concepts) methods in `std::basic_string`, typically the whole family of `find` methods, `insert` has an overload with `size_type`, `append`, and so on.

On a subjective view, I think it is better to have a `std::basic_string` that does not behave like other containers because it is not (I am not sure that the standard requires `std::basic_string` to be a `SequenceContainer` or anything alike).

<sub><sup>1</sup> You cannot return iterators here because you want a new `std::basic_string`, so you would have a method taking iterators but returning an object... I would find this much more disturbing than having  `pos`/`count` instead of `first`/`last`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't say why, I wasn't there, but there is a range constructor for the [begin, end) convention you missed.

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```